# Dollar sign on danish keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, keyboard

I'm running a macbook pro on English language, with a danish keyboard (Microsoft Ergonomic 400) - for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the dollar sign out of it.

I'm used to press AltGr+4 to get it. Now it just gives me the £ sign.

Comment: Mac doesn't have an AltGr key, btw, & I'm not certain how it would read one pressed on a Win keyboard.

Comment: MS keyboards are not printed according the Apple Danish layout.  Both the topmost leftmost key and alt shift 3 should give you $, assuming you have your OS X set the Danish input source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the layout may have been modified.

Try using <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.

You can also check what key combinations produce what characters by [enabling the On-Screen-Keyboard](http://osxdaily.com/2013/06/21/mac-virtual-keyboard-os-x/) :

> - Open System Preferences and go to “Keyboard”, and look under the “Keyboard” tab
> - Check the box next to “Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar”
> - Enable the virtual keyboard input in Mac OS X
> - Pull down the newly visible Keyboard menu and choose “Show Keyboard Viewer”

Comment: Thanks, this one works - I didn't try the combo of altgr+shift, and rest of my programming needs seem to come from that combo for now.

Comment: Just curious, do you not also get $ with the topmost leftmost key (or if not that, the key to the left of the z)?

Comment: Damn, apparently the one left of z also gives $, the one left of 1 gives <

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried top-left key (the one left of 1 and under the ESC) - there is where $ sign in danish Mac keymap should be.